# Can someone guide me through this logic error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove all the elements in arraylist `deck` but for some reason `deck.size()` which should be 52 returns 26 and only 26 of the elements are removed.

```
public void remove()
{
    int k = 0;
    while(k < deck.size())
    {
        deck.remove(0);
        k++;
    }   
}
```

I called `numberOfCards()` in `main` which returns `deck.size()` and it returns 52. So I have no idea why the `deck.size()` in remove only return 26.

Comment: What are the elements of Deck. Please show us the type

Comment: theyre of type Card.  Its a user defined class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the computer is doing exactly what you told it to do.

- First, it sets `k` to 0.
- Then it calls `deck.size()` which returns 52. `0 < 52`, so it enters the loop.
- Then it removes the first element from `deck`.
- Then it increments `k` (which sets it to 1).
- Then it calls `deck.size()` which returns 51. `1 < 51`, so it enters the loop again.
- Then it removes the first element from `deck`.
- Then it increments `k` (which sets it to 2).
- Then it calls `deck.size()` which returns 50. `2 < 50`, so it enters the loop again.
- ...
- Then it increments `k` (which sets it to 25).
- Then it calls `deck.size()` which returns 27. `25 < 27`, so it enters the loop again.
- Then it removes the first element from `deck`.
- Then it increments `k` (which sets it to 26).
- Then it calls `deck.size()` which returns 26. `26 < 26` is **not** true, so it jumps to the end of the loop, even though there are still 26 elements left in `deck`.

Answer (score 2):

You remove elements, decreasing the size, while reasing `k`, which reaches an equilibrium at half the size of the deck.

The while loop should be:

```
while(deck.size()>0)
    deck.remove(0);
```

Comment: Your solution is simple but it can be simpler. See my answer

Comment: @rtruszk, very true. My answer is also hopelessly inefficient since with each removal, all elements have to be swapped one place to the front :P However, I just wanted to point out his logic error ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're incrementing k while the size of the deck is reducing in each iteration, so k and deck.size() will "meet" halfway through, so at 26.

You can fix it by simply doing this:

```
public void remove()
{
  int k = deck.size();
  while(k != 0)
  {
     deck.remove(0);
     k--;
  }   
}
```

Comment: WOW, i just looked at my notes and I had make a note of that.  Thank you so so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel. To remove all elements from list you can simply call:

```
deck.clear();
```

This will remove all elements from the list.